# PDO uncaught exception issue

Tags: php, pdo, connection

hey there i have this connenction:

```
$config = array(
    'host'      => '****',
    'username'  => '****',
    'password'  => '****',
    'dbname'    => '****'
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

but i get this error:

```
 Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host
```

i already tried to change ' to " , but still error, anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `host` value stored in the variable `$config['host']` may not be right

Answer (score 1):

Your application is unable to connect to the database. Check that `$config['host]` is set correctly and points to a reachable mysql server instance.